# Calculate positions to place objects around a wheel

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 3D slot machine. For the reel, I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the X, Y, Z positions as well as thee Y rotation to place the objects like cherrys, oranges, etc.. Overall, there are going to be 28 pieces.

I thought that calculating the circumference would help but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Well.  If you know how many there are its not hard to do myvar = 360/28 and position them every myvar.. what did you try

Comment: Honestly, I had no idea where to even begin. Too many long days working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually really simple and done in a few lines

```c#
public GameObject prefab;

public float radius;
public float amount;

// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Start()
{
    var angle = 0f;

    for (var i = 0; i <= amount; i++)
    {
        var y = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * radius;
        var z = - Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * radius;

        var obj = Instantiate(prefab, transform);
        obj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, y, z);
        obj.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(angle, 0, 0);

        angle += (360f / amount);
    }
}

// just for demo
private void Update()
{
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Time.time * 45, 0, 0);
}
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your example! Is there a way I can resize the prefab so 28 of them will fit??

Comment: I have the size part figured out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is more of a math problem then anything else really. Now assuming that you are not a total beginner with Unity I will not write you code for your solution, but just generaly describe it.

First thing you need to be inputed is radius, this will determine how far away from the center of the circle should your items be. You can just take the scale of the circle object and multiply it by some variable value. Then you also need the number of ticks that you wish to place around the circle as a variable. In your case this can be 27. Then divide 360 by that variable and you should get a segment of the circle for each item.

Last thing you need to do is put a for loop for each tick on the circle and in there spawn an item on point where you get the point position by taking a vector from the center of the circle to the top point and multiply it by an Euler that has as many degrees as the segment size that we got earlier. For the rotation of the object, you just need to subtract it with the same segment size and thats basically it.

Hope this helps. If you need some code clarification I can provide it later today.